# Application is crashing while creating quickfix group

Tags: c#, quickfix

If I create a group like:

```
QuickFix.Group group = new QuickFix.Group(3, 50)
```

it's working perfectly. If I create group like

```
QuickFix.Group group = new QuickFix.Group(73, 50)
// or
QuickFix.Group group = new QuickFix.Group(555, 600)
```

I am getting an exception like below:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory.
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at FIX.FieldMap.{dtor}(FieldMap* )
   at FIX.Message.{dtor}(Message* )
   at FIX.Message.__vecDelDtor(Message* , UInt32 )
   at QuickFix.Message.Finalize()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Excellent observation, but what is your question? What tools are you using? What is this "quickfix"?

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1224985/user1224985 this is quite a common error between clr and native code. When I have a moment I will have a closer look at what is causing it in this case. note that you have to have a datadictionary in your settings to use groups - that results in this error so is probably a good place to start looking

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'll take a punt...

Some Googling leads me to believe you're using the managed C++ wrapper of the [QuickFIX engine](http://www.quickfixengine.org/). Given that this is a managed wrapper around unmanaged code, and the fact you're getting an exception one might expect to see in C++ leads me to believe this is probably simply a bug in that library.

I'd suggest you may get better results from their mailing lists (see http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickfix/support).